# Dedicated Server, SyntaxError, Discord Bot javascript

Tags: javascript, sh, dedicated-server

On localhost everything is fine, when i installed it on the dedicated server and when i start it 'kireina.sh' following error occurs:
https://ibb.co/6XBhHz1

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:140:18)
at node.js:1043:3
```

Comment: Well, what's different between the two environments?  Do they use the same version of Node?

Comment: sorry, troble is solved, im not download nodejs, heh :D

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting. It is kinda required on Stack Overflow to post a [mcve] so we can help you and understand the problem..

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you provided, the error is on the `async` keyword. This means that the version of Node.js you are running does not support [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). You will need at least node.js v7.6 in order to use async/await.

You can find instructions for installing the latest version of Node.js [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).